# How can I delete a collection from an ArangoDB using the WebInterface?

Tags: arangodb

folks. I'm relatively new to ArangoDB and trying to do something fairly straight forward. I created a number of collections to test things out, and now I need to delete those collections. All my searching only turns up ways to delete documents, not collections.

I'm using version 3.5.3. My OS is windows and my browser is Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Log in to the ArangoDB web UI
2. Select your database
3. Click on the 'Collections' menu on the left
4. Click on the collection you want to delete
5. Click on the 'Settings' tab at the top of the screen
6. Click on the red 'Delete' button to remove the collection

Hope that helps

I'd also recommend going through the free ArangoDB training courses at [ArangoDB](https://www.arangodb.com/arangodb-training-center/) to help you get up to speed.